# How can I automatically deploy my app after a git push on multiple servers

Tags: git, deployment, push, webhooks

I have a system written in PHP, running on various clients over a VPN. The code is versioned in Bitbucket.

I would like a solution to automate the process in all these clients, manually is becoming unviable.

Comment: "Continuous Integration" and "Continuous Delivery" are the keywords you should google for.

Comment: You would need a Continuous Integration service like Jenkins or others that would handle the deployment.